# .split() and triple spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a small script to convert morse code into plain text.

For example:

```
"···· · −·−−   ·−−− ··− −·· ·"
```

would return `"HEYJUDE"`. But, I would like it to be `"HEY JUDE"` instead, with a space in between the two words.

There are 3 spaces in between the morse code for `"HEY"` and `"JUDE"`, I don't think `.split()` can help me here. Could you give me a pointer?

```
def decodeMorse(morse_code):
    morseDict = {".-" : "A", "-..." : "B", "-.-." : "C", "-.." : "D",
                 "." : "E", "..-." : "F", "--." : "G", "...." : "H",
                 ".." : "I", ".---" : "J", "-.-" : "K", ".-..": "L",
                 "--" : "M", "-." : "N", "---" : "O", ".--." : "P",
                 "--.-" : "Q", ".-." : "R", "..." : "S", "-" : "T",
                 "..-" : "U", "...-" : "V", ".--" : "W", "-..-" : "X",
                 "-.--" : "Y", "--.." : "Z"
                 }
    cipher = morse_code.split(" ")
    plain = []
    for n in cipher:
        plain.append(morseDict[n])
    plain = "".join(plain)
    return plain
```

Comment: split will help you. just use `.split("   ")` ()

Comment: Split `morse_code` into a list by three spaces then single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first line of `decodeMorse()`, you can replace the middle space among 3 adjacent spaces to any different char:

```
morse_code = morse_code.replace('   ', ' @ ')
```

then add this char to `morseDict` .

```
morseDict['@']=' '
```

The rest of your code need no modification.

Comment: *The rest of your code need no modification* - except that it should be `split()` and not `split("")`. Nice answer!

Comment: That's a really neat trick mate! Replacing the triple space with something else and adding an extra entry into the dictionary to recognize it as a triple space? Thanks, I'll be sure to remember this!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could two steps of split, the first one would be

```
.split('   ') #with 3 spaces
```

to decode word by word and then decoding each word, adding your desired space between then!

Answer (score 0):

If your input looks like this, you can split them first by triple space and then iterate on each word separately.

```
code = ".... . −.−−   .−−− ..− −.. ."
words = code.split("   ")
```